# Pandas : Replace string column values (equal, contains, case)

Tags: python, string, pandas, replace, contains

I have datafarme as below.

```
ID   COUNTRY   GENDER    AGE  V1   V2   V3   V4   V5
1    1    1    53   APPLE     apple     bosck     APPLE123  xApple111t
2    2    2    51   BEKO beko SIMSUNG   SamsungO123    ttBeko111t
3    3    1    24   SAMSUNG   bosch     SEMSUNG   BOSC1123  uuSAMSUNG111t
```

I want to replace to np.nan if there are same value in list or contain specific value.
I tried below but occurred error.

```
remove_list = ['APPLE', 'BEKO']

remove_contain_list = ['SUNG', 'bosc']

df.iloc[:,4:].str.replace(remove_list, np.nan, case=False) # exact match & case sensitive
df.iloc[:,4:].str.contains(remove_contain_list, np.nan, case=False) # contain & case sensitive
```

How can I solve these problems?

Comment: could u format ur code properly? data should be indented with at least four spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create `MultiIndex Series` by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), get masks for exact and partial matches by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) with lowercase values and [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html), replace by [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) (default value for replace is `NaN`, so no necessary specify) and last [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) and assign back:

```
remove_list = ['APPLE', 'BEKO']
remove_contain_list = ['SUNG', 'bosc']

s = df.iloc[:,4:].stack(dropna=False)
m1 = s.str.lower().isin([x.lower() for x in remove_list])
m2 = s.str.contains('|'.join(remove_contain_list), case=False)
s = s.mask(m1 | m2)

df.iloc[:,4:] = s.unstack()
print (df)
   ID  COUNTRY  GENDER  AGE   V1   V2   V3        V4          V5
0   1        1       1   53  NaN  NaN  NaN  APPLE123  xApple111t
1   2        2       2   51  NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN  ttBeko111t
2   3        3       1   24  NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN         NaN
```

EDIT: You can replace mask to background color if match in [`Styler.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.apply.html):

```
def color(x): 
    c1 = 'background-color: yellow'
    c = ''

    remove_list = ['APPLE', 'BEKO']
    remove_contain_list = ['SUNG', 'bosc']

    s = x.iloc[:,4:].stack(dropna=False)
    m1 = s.str.lower().isin([i.lower() for i in remove_list])
    m2 = s.str.contains('|'.join(remove_contain_list), case=False)
    m = m1| m2

    df1 = pd.DataFrame(c, index=x.index, columns=x.columns)
    mask = m.unstack(fill_value=False).reindex(x.columns, fill_value=False, axis=1)   
    df1 = df1.mask(mask, c1)
    return df1

df.style.apply(color,axis=None)
```

Comment: Thank you and Can I know the  means of   '|'.join ?

Comment: @purplecollar - It means regex OR - `first value of list OR second value of list`

Comment: Same condition as above, how can I change the backgroud color to yellow instead of replace?

Comment: @purplecollar - so for `remove_list` matching is yellow, for `remove_contain_list` is red? How looks expected output?

Comment: If the column value corresponds to remove_list or contain remove_contain_list, I want to change the background color of the column to yellow.

Comment: I run new code, but occurred ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (161,46) into shape (164,149)

Comment: I have tried and return this... ValueError: Boolean array expected for the condition, not object

Comment: @purplecollar - For me working perfectly, can you test with sample data ? `df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 2, 3], 'COUNTRY': [1, 2, 3], 'GENDER': [1, 2, 1], 'AGE': [53, 51, 24], 'V1': ['APPLE', 'BEKO', 'SAMSUNG'], 'V2': ['apple', 'beko', 'bosch'], 'V3': ['bosck', 'SIMSUNG', 'SEMSUNG'], 'V4': ['APPLE123', 'SamsungO123', 'BOSC1123'], 'V5': ['xApple111t', 'ttBeko111t', 'uuSAMSUNG111t']})` ?

Comment: sample data working perfectly. For my real data, there are lots of NaN values.

Comment: @purplecollar - Can you change `.stack()` to `.stack(dropna=False)` ? Answer edited.

Comment: @purplecollar - Supeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeer ;) I am really happy ;)